# How to get index values for multiple matches in the same line in awk?

Tags: awk

I know the following expression:

```
echo "bob alice robert alice" | awk '{print index($0,"alice")}'
5
```

Will output the index of the first alice match, is there any way to get the index of all matches?, eg:

```
echo "bob alice robert alice" | awk 'unknown magic'
5:18
```

Comment: actually this is no magic but a simple substring shift loop. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With POSIX tools chest:

```
echo "bob alice robert alice"| p=alice awk '
{
  while(1) {
    $0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    match($0, ENVIRON["p"])
    if (RSTART == 0) break
    i = i ? i+RSTART+RLENGTH-1 : RSTART
    print i
  }
}' | paste -sd: -
5:18
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do your job:

```
echo "bob alice robert alice" |\
awk '{
    s=$0
    o=0
    m="alice"
    l=length(m)
    i=index(s,m)
    while (i>0) {
        o+=i
        print o
        s=substr(s,i+l)
        o+=l-1
        i=index(s,m)
    }
}'
```

To format with the ':' (colon) you can pipe through

```
paste -s |tr '\t' ':'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "bob alice robert alice"| awk '
{for( i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    if ( $i == "alice") {
          printf index($0,"alice") ":"
          gsub("alice","xxxxx",$i)
     }
}
print " "
}'
```